# Manipulate duplicates the output

Tags: manipulate

I not sure if the question has been asked or not. I tried to find something similar without success.

I have this small code:

```
Manipulate[Plot[Sin[a x], {x, 0, 2}], {a, 1, 10}]
```

The output is ok. when I changed a using the Manipulate controller bar, the output is ok too. But when I used the keyboard to enter value of a and then Enter, I get a duplicate output:

[image]

Did I do something wrong to get this output?

Thank you

Comment: I can reproduce that only for Shift+Enter event or numeric keyboard Enter. It always has been a little bit annoying.

Comment: Very annoying..

Comment: Shift+Enter means evaluate the current cell (if it is evaluatable).  When you evaluate a `Manipulate` output, it evaluates to another (instance of a) `Manipulate`, as well as converting the output cell to an input cell as shown by the In/Out tags in your screen shot.  However annoying it is, the behavior is quite consistent with the documented behavior sifht+enter, which must be familiar to any somewhat experienced user.

Comment: Using Enter (Return keyboard button without shift) solves the issue.

Comment: I use Tab myself, but it changes focus and selects the `InputField` text.

Comment: Yes, Tab works also. Return works without selecting the InputField text

Answer (score 2):

Your code defines the `Control` to be a `Slider` by default.  Typing into a different device, the `InputField`, yields a separate computation and separate output cell.

If you'd like to change the `Control` for input to be an `InputField` so you can type different values of `a` without producing different output cells, try this:

```
Manipulate[Plot[Sin[a x], {x, 0, 2}], {{a, 5}, InputField}]
```

Answer (score 0):

A workaround I use is to put a semicolon at the end of the graph in the Manipulate Cell, this prevents printing more copies of the graph each time data is entered in the InputField.